# How do I Mail Merge from a SQL DB to Word 2013 with a date filter?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2013, mail-merge

I have a SQL database view that returns the data I need for my mail merge. This data needs to be filtered by a Date Range. i.e. `>1/1/2014` and `<3/1/2014`

I have attempted to put it in the filter box of my merge it just gives a generic db error.
The field that I want to sort on is a `DateTime` field.

What I would really like is to automate the prompting for Start and End date so that the merge can be done by clerical staff. Is this possible?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: First things first; does the merge work without the date filter?

Comment: Yes it works without the date filter

Comment: What do you mean by "generic db error"? Is there a specific message?

Comment: (1) which SQL DB and (2) if you can get into the VBA Editor's immediate mode, what does ?ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.QueryString show?

Comment: The exact error I'm getting: "An operation cannot be completed because of database engine errors"

Comment: Word generates different SQL depending on the data source. If it's Access/Jet, the Query will use > #1/1/2014#. If it's SQL Server, it will use > '01/01/2014'. My guess is that it will use the latter for anything (such as MySQL) that it doesn't understand, so if that is the wrong syntax for that database, you would probably see that particular error.

Comment: Clarification: It is going against an older MS SQL database.

Comment: So far I haven't been able to replicate using either OLE DB or ODBC against either a recent, or a SQL Server 2000 DB. I encounter a different problem in some cases with an ODBC connection. So although it is difficult to answer your "Is this possible?" question with confidence, as long as you can construct a query that Word can execute, you should be able to create a VBA UserForm that prompts for start and end dates and issues a suitable OpenDataSource command. FWIW, when Word can't connect, I generally start by trying to connect from Excel and try to figure out what Word is doing wrong.